# Spring Cloud Data Flow Stream files to HDFS

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm new to Spring Cloud Data Flow. I use v 1.7.3 and want to create a simple stream that scans a directory for new files and pushes them to HDFS. I have the following definition:

`file --cron='* * * * * *' --mode=ref --directory=/dir | hdfs --fs-uri=hdfs://myhdpmaster:8020`

When I deploy my stream I have two issues:

1. No matter which file `mode` I use there is only a hdfs-sink-0.txt created that has no content at all or lines that appear to print the default toString() output (e.g. '[B@7d5bfc85').
2. When I put new files in the directory, the message is not received by the HDFS sink, although I see in the file source logs that the message was created.

The output of my hdfs sink:

```
2019-01-25 12:21:06.330  INFO 63 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version : 0.10.1.1
2019-01-25 12:21:06.330  INFO 63 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId : f10ef2720b03b247
2019-01-25 12:21:06.338  INFO 63 --- [           main] s.i.k.i.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter : started org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter@67110f71
2019-01-25 12:21:06.338  INFO 63 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {message-handler:inbound.testhdfs1.file.testhdfs1} as a subscriber to the 'bridge.testhdfs1.file' channel
2019-01-25 12:21:06.338  INFO 63 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started inbound.testhdfs1.file.testhdfs1
2019-01-25 12:21:06.340  INFO 63 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 2147483647
2019-01-25 12:21:06.476  INFO 63 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 47888 (http)
2019-01-25 12:21:06.483  INFO 63 --- [           main] s.c.s.a.h.s.k.HdfsSinkKafka10Application : Started HdfsSinkKafka10Application in 17.593 seconds (JVM running for 18.756)
2019-01-25 12:21:08.250  INFO 63 --- [           -C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : Discovered coordinator kafka:9092 (id: 2147482646 rack: null) for group testhdfs1.
2019-01-25 12:21:08.256  INFO 63 --- [           -C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : Revoking previously assigned partitions [] for group testhdfs1
2019-01-25 12:21:08.256  INFO 63 --- [           -C-1] o.s.c.s.b.k.KafkaMessageChannelBinder$3  : partitions revoked:[]
2019-01-25 12:21:08.256  INFO 63 --- [           -C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : (Re-)joining group testhdfs1
2019-01-25 12:21:08.522  INFO 63 --- [           -C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : Successfully joined group testhdfs1 with generation 1
2019-01-25 12:21:08.526  INFO 63 --- [           -C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : Setting newly assigned partitions [testhdfs1.file-0] for group testhdfs1
2019-01-25 12:21:08.735  INFO 63 --- [           -C-1] o.s.c.s.b.k.KafkaMessageChannelBinder$3  : partitions assigned:[testhdfs1.file-0]
2019-01-25 12:21:23.238  INFO 63 --- [           -L-1] o.s.i.codec.kryo.CompositeKryoRegistrar  : registering [40, java.io.File] with serializer org.springframework.integration.codec.kryo.FileSerializer
2019-01-25 12:21:23.353  INFO 63 --- [           -L-1] o.s.d.h.s.o.AbstractDataStreamWriter     : Creating output for path /data/hdfs-sink-0.txt
```

Comment: Did it work finally? What changes did you made

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't copy files into hdfs with `hdfs` sink as it's just meant to write arbitrary messages received from sources. Reason you see zero length of that files is that file is still open and not flushed. [hdfs sink readme](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/hdfs/blob/master/spring-cloud-starter-stream-sink-hdfs/README.adoc) contains config options and if you i.e. use `idle-timeout` or `rollover` settings you're starting to see files written.

Comment: Thanks, how would I approach writing my own HDFS sink, considering that spring-hadoop reaches EOL in April?